# Angular 8 - Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'javascript : void(0)'

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an angular 8 application in which I am using external dependency which generates paginated table in my application. I just need to pass json data to it and it will do the rest for me.

So the paginated table generates links for next and previous page. If I hover it it will show `localhost:4200/javascript : void(0)`. As per my knowledge, my app should ignore this hyperlink as underlying scripts must have onClick function for this.

But still I am getting below error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'javascript%20:%20void%280%29'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'javascript%20:%20void%280%29'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2459)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2440)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at zone.js:913
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26247)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1693)
```

Below is my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: HEALTH,
    pathMatch: FULL,
    loadChildren: './health/health.module#HealthModule'
  },
  {
    path: EMPTY_STRING,
    resolve: {
      LoggedInDetail: LoggedInDetailResolve
   },
    component: FullPageLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'index',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: EMPTY_STRING,
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: TEMPLATE_ROUTE,
        component: TemplateComponent
      }
    ]
  }

];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [LoggedInDetailResolve]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Please note I am using hash based URL's

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
```

Comment: Are you dynamically adding HTML into the DOM?  Angular will try and sanitize that and remove javascript.  Sounds like you have href set to javascript void, and Angular is sanitizing that so its just a string which is why its trying to add it to the URL.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo?

Comment: Please share your pagination code. There's a problem with how you route and you must not use sth like `javascript : void(0)`!

Answer (score -1):

Please remove the  **pathMatch: FULL** from your code.

Or you can use as **pathMatch: 'prefix'**

**pathMatch:'full':** In this case, when app is launched on localhost:4200 (or some server) the default page will be welcome screen, since the url will be https://localhost:4200/

If https://localhost:4200/surendra this will redirect to pageNotFound screen because of path:'**' wildcard

**pathMatch:'prefix':** If the routes have { path: '', redirectTo: 'initial', pathMatch: 'prefix' }, now this will never reach the wildcard route since every url would match path:'' defined.

Comment: This did not work for me. What is difference between FULL & Prefix

Comment: have you removed the **pathMatch** from your parent.

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: I tried both options but still did not work for me.